# How to get all the values of input array element jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my html input elements

```
<input type="text" name="pname[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="pname[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="pname[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="pname[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="pname[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="pname[]" value="" />
```

How can I get all the values of `pname` array using Jquery

Comment: i cannot understand.. want to get the values of the text box..?

Comment: Yes I want to get all textbox values in array format

Comment: use Array mapping feature

Comment: Both are not same questions @RajaprabhuAravindasamy read it properly.

Comment: @user3707303 Yes both are not same, your question contains less words while comparing with the linked question. You got it..

Comment: No one will use same number of words and same format. Everyone will write in their own way it's not a thing at all.... @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  If is there any errors then SO(stackoverflow) will returns error while submitting question and many people here understood my question and given correct answer tooo..

Comment: use this: for input 1 `$('[name="pname[]"]:eq(0)').val();` input 2 `$('[name="pname[]"]:eq(1)').val();` input 3 `$('[name="pname[]"]:eq(2)').val();` and ...

Answer (score 188, accepted):

By Using map

```
var values = $("input[name='pname[]']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Comment: what does get() do? What does this return without the get()?

Comment: get() method returns a specified element from map object. Without .get() you will get entire map object with things like length, context, etc.

Comment: Where is `get()` defined?  Is that a jQuery thing?  An Array.map thing?

Comment: this is how you got values. How to get keys?

Answer (score 35):

You can use [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return value.

As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

*Use*

```
var arr = $('input[name="pname[]"]').map(function () {
    return this.value; // $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Comment: this is how you got values. How to get keys?

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
function getvalues(){
var inps = document.getElementsByName('pname[]');
for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
var inp=inps[i];
    alert("pname["+i+"].value="+inp.value);
}
}
```

Here is [***`Demo`***](http://jsfiddle.net/5jd8N/1/).

Comment: @Genki, Glad that it helped someone! Cheers! Happy coding :).