# Insert array data in PHP passing through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I'm trying to insert array value in `php` passing through `ajax`, but I am not succeeding. I think the problem is in `ajax` while sending array variable.  My HTML form is as below.

```
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <td><input type="number" id="navid"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Menu NPL</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="menunpl[]"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Menu ENG</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="menueng[]"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I've passed value as

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var navid = $("#navid").val();
    var menunpl = $("input[name='menunpl[]']" ).val()
    var menueng = $("input[name='menueng[]']" ).val()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert_nav.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {navid:navid,menunpl:menunpl,menueng:menueng},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#nav')[0].reset();
        }
    });
});
```

But In serverside, it says  Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

```
if (isset($_POST["navid"]) && !empty($_POST["navid"])) {
    foreach ($_POST['menunpl'] AS $key => $item){
        $query1 =$con->prepare("INSERT INTO menu(cid, title, en_title) VALUES (:navid, :menunpl, :menueng)");
        $query1->bindParam(':menunpl',$item);
        $query1->bindParam(':menueng',$_POST["menueng"][$key]);
        $query1->bindParam(':navid', $_POST["navid"]);
        $query1->execute();
        $msg1 = 'Menu has inserted';    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you `foreach` over a string in PHP?  I'm fairly certain from what you have shown that `$_POST['menunpl']` would be a string.

Comment: Yes you can foreach a string to enumerate caracters.why array menunpl, is there many <input text menunpl> ?

Comment: @EricV. yes <input text menunpl> can be added by user.

Comment: I think the problem is the way you get the value from javascript : look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24503913/2332589

Comment: @AnandHmt, your error is in `ajax`. In this way you can't pass array variable. Change `var menunpl = $("input[name='menunpl[]']" ).val()` to
`var menunpl = []; $('input[name="menunpl[]"]').each( function() {menunpl.push(this.value);});` and other variable as this. This should work. And do not forget to add array to `id` in html and ajax.

Comment: `var menunpl = $('input[name="menunpl[]"]').map(function(){ return this.value; }).get()` would achieve the same thing