# I have created a form dynamically using jquery, now I am having trouble in submitting the form, any solution for this would be highly appreciated

Tags: jquery

I have created a form dynamically using jquery, now I am having trouble in submitting the form.

```
$(document).on('click','.answer',function() {

var a = $(this).data('id'); //getter
if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('textarea').length == 0) {
$("#answer_form").remove();
$(this).parent().parent().parent().append('<form class="answer_form" id="answer_form"><textarea rows="4" name="answer" class="form-control"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="business_id" readonly value="<?php echo $single_ad->id ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="question_id" id="question_id" readonly value=""/><div class="form-check form-group" style="margin-top: 5px;"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="answer_secret" name="answer_secret"><label class="form-check-label" for="Secret">Secret<span class="secret">(Only Owner of this business can see this question.)</span></label></div><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="btn-sm btn-danger submit_answer">Submit</a></form>'); 
}
$('#question_id').val(a);

});
```

This is how i am submitting form, and below part is how i am trying to save this form, I would really appreciate some help

```
$(".submit_answer").click(".answer_form", function (e) {
event.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
if (id == '') {
var id1 = '';
} else {
var id1 = id;
}
var formData = new FormData($(".answer_form")[0]);
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>creview/save_answer/"+id1,
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
async: false,
success: function (data) {
var JsonObject= JSON.parse(data);
if (JsonObject.success) {
$.notify({
title: "Complete : ",
message: JsonObject.message,
icon: 'mdi mdi-checkbox-marked-circle'
},{
type: "success",
placement: {
from: "top",
align: "right"
},
});
setTimeout(function() {
window.location.reload();
}, 2000);

} else {
$.notify({
title: "Error : ",
message: JsonObject.message,
icon: 'mdi mdi-alert'
},{
type: "danger",
placement: {
from: "top",
align: "right"
},
});
}
},
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
});
});
```

Comment: Please format code entries so other people have less trouble deciphering your code and try to restrict the presented code to the most important parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is correct but I have a doubt about your passing data...

It's better you generate a model of your data by choosing every **input types** and make a structure to pass them. just like in bellow [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503865/how-to-get-all-the-values-of-input-array-element-jquery)

a model sample can be this:

```
var modelToPost = {
               
                OfficeId: officeId,
                Title: "Title...",
                DayCount: 0,
                BoardingType: "boartdingtype",
                Comment: "...Comment",
                ItemsList: "Items...."
            };
```